# How do I make the code run in a FOR loop? Instead of so many IF

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

how can i use a `FOR` loop in this code?
instead using a lot of `IF` questions.
I've tried lots of ways to make it work but without success.
I'd love to help me solve this through a smart loop.
This is for software that calculates shelf placement and drawer placement.
I need you to help me solve this problem.
I want somthing like this:

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= NishCount; i++)
            {
                lblNish + i + .Text = nish + i + .ToString();
            }
```

this is the code:

```
            if (NishCount == 1 && MdfCount == 0)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblSho.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblMDF1.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
                lblMDF2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
            }
            if (NishCount == 2 && MdfCount == 0)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = nish2.ToString();

                lblSho.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblMDF1.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
                lblMDF2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
            }
            if (NishCount == 1 && MdfCount == 1)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblSho.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();
                lblMDF2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
            }
            if (NishCount == 2 && MdfCount == 1)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = nish2.ToString();

                lblSho.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();
                lblMDF2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
            }
            if (NishCount == 1 && MdfCount == 2)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblSho.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();
                lblMDF2.Text = MDF2.ToString();
            }
            if (NishCount == 2 && MdfCount == 2)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = nish2.ToString();

                lblSho.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();
                lblMDF2.Text = MDF2.ToString();
            }
            if (NishCount == 1 && MdfCount == 0 && SNCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblSho.Text = shocev.ToString();

                lblMDF1.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
                lblMDF2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
            }
            if (NishCount == 2 && MdfCount == 0 && SNCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = nish2.ToString();

                lblSho.Text = shocev.ToString();

                lblMDF1.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
                lblMDF2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
            }
            if (NishCount == 1 && MdfCount == 1 && SNCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblSho.Text = shocev.ToString();

                lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();
                lblMDF2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
            }
            if (NishCount == 2 && MdfCount == 1 && SNCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = nish2.ToString();

                lblSho.Text = shocev.ToString();

                lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();
                lblMDF2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
            }
            if (NishCount == 1 && MdfCount == 2 && SNCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = lblSho.ToString();

                lblSho.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

                lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();
                lblMDF2.Text = MDF2.ToString();
            }
            if (NishCount == 2 && MdfCount == 2 && SNCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
                lblNish2.Text = nish2.ToString();

                lblSho.Text = shocev.ToString();

                lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();
                lblMDF2.Text = MDF2.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: You need to use switch case here... For loop won't be useful here.

Comment: how to do it?
can you write a code?

Comment: Can you change the string literals to English so that we can see which ones are the same and which are different more easily? (and preferably the variable names too) You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch to learn about switch case in C#. Try using it in your code and ask question here is you face any problem in that.

Comment: @Sweeper i change it to english.

Comment: The best way is to use a case.  You would need to map your three inputs (NishCount [2 bits], MdfCount [2 bits], and SNCheckBox.Checked[1 bit]) to a number.  So use following : byte value = (byte)((NishCount << 3) | (MdfCount < 1) | (SNCheckBox.Checked? 1 : 0));

Comment: @jdweng Can you give more details or you post a new comment with the code?

Comment: Suppose NishCount = 2,  MdfCount = 2, and SNCheckBox.Checked = true.  Then value is 16 (two shifted left 3 times) Or 4 (two shifted left 1 time) Or 1 (true) = 0x15.

Comment: @jdweng Can you please post a code for i can test it? i dont know how to write this code ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start by initializing them all:

```
lblNish1.Text = "הזן מידות";
lblNish2.Text = "הזן מידות";

lblSho.Text = "הזן מידות";

lblMDF1.Text = "הזן מידות";
lblMDF2.Text = "הזן מידות";
```

Then set them like needed:

```
if (NishCount >= 1) 
    lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();

if (NishCount >= 2) 
    lblNish2.Text = nish2.ToString();

if (SNCheckBox.Checked)
    lblSho.Text = shocev.ToString();

if (MdfCount >= 1) 
    lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();

if (MdfCount >= 2) 
    lblMDF2.Text = MDF2.ToString();
```

There's probably a more elegant solution if we would know all your code.

Comment: @אריפרץ well this is easy to read and might be all you need in this case.

Comment: @אריפרץ There are many _good_ ways of doing it, any of them can be the "best" if you argue hard enough. I think this is okay, unless you want to drastically change the structure of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a for loop.  You logic simplifies to following

```
            lblNish1.Text = nish1.ToString();
            lblNish2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

            lblSho.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

            lblMDF1.Text = "ENTER VALUES";
            lblMDF2.Text = "ENTER VALUES";

            if (NishCount == 2)
            {
                lblNish2.Text = nish2.ToString();
            }
            switch(MdfCount)
            {
                case 1:
                    lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    lblMDF1.Text = MDF1.ToString();
                    lblMDF2.Text = MDF2.ToString();
                    break;
            }
            if(SNCheckBox.Checked && !((NishCount == 1) && (MdfCount == 2)))
            {
                lblSho.Text = shocev.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: thank you very much, can you send me a mail?                this is my mail: ari.perez25.06@gmail.com

Comment: if i have 50 times, i will wrote 50 cases?

Comment: It is hard to tell the best method for reducing the amount of code.  Usually the best method is setting a different bit for each condition.  So you have 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256 (and so on) where each bit is a different condition.  If you used a long, then you have 64 bits and 64 conditions.  You would still need 64 if statements but only one line of code in each if.  Your code repeats duplicate code in each if statement.